# Automatically convert all file and folder names to lowercase and set permissions to 644 on upload with vsftpd

Tags: linux, ftp

I'd like to have vsftpd convert all uploaded filenames matching `/home/$USER/public_html/*` to lowercase, and set the permissions to 644 upon upload. Is this possible and how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vsftpd can't lowercase filenames, you may be able to get [proftpd to do it though](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Rewrite.html). There is a configuration directive

> file_open_mode - 
>       The permissions with which uploaded files are created. Umasks are applied on top of this value. You may wish to change to 0777 if you
>   want uploaded files to be executable.
>
> ```
> Default: 0666
> ```

You can probably adjust it to meet your requirements.